# Making Document Libraries visible to some users and not others

Tags: 2007, permissions, document-library

I have several document libraries that I would like to list on the front page but make visible to certain users only.
If I set it up this way:

-UserLib1, user1 has read permissions

-UserLib2, user2 has read permissions,

-UserLib3, user3 has read permissions, etc.

UserLib1,2,... are added as webparts to the site.  user1,2,3... are in "visitors" group for the site.

Then user1 can still see UserLib2 with the "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource." message.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of giving permissions to direct users, can you create three Sharepoint groups and give each library permission for the respective groups? 
UserGroup 1 -> Access to UserLib1 
UserGroup 2 -> Access to UserLib2 
UserGroup 3 -> Access to UserLib3 
Then you can add one or more user to each group (and also to the Visitors group).

Then you can use 'Audience Targeting' settings for the webparts on the front page and hide the web parts for the un-authorized users alltogether. In Audience Targeting give Group name of the group that's supposed to be able to See that particular library.

Comment: this worked well - users only see their corresponding document libraries. Additional note: I had to add all users to the "visitors" group to give read permissions to the front page; otherwise users will get "Access denied" error.